# How to Restore Documents Store on Cloud Folder After Re-install?

Tags: ubuntu-one

It seems to me Ubuntu one cloud folder remembers booth email ID and Device and Device is identified by GID which changes if you re-install Ubuntu on the same device. How do I retrive my cloud folder from the that was generated during the sync of previous installation. I see the other device in my account but I cannot connect to it.

Answer (score 1):

During the re-installation I have used the same user-name and the same name of the computer.
My synchronized folder were in my /home. At the end of the process I could download what was synchronized